# In Ruby on Rails, how do I default to a locale when it is omitted from the url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a Rails app with some internationalization, I have it setting the locale through a url parameter, like this:

/en/post/show/4 for english
/ja/post/show/4 for japanese

My routes:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect "", :controller => "post", :action => "index"
  map.connect "/:locale", :controller => "post", :action => "index"
  map.connect "post/show/:id/:tag_title", :controller => "post", :action => "show", :requirements => {:id => /\d+/}, :path_prefix => '/:locale'
  map.connect ":controller/:action/:id.:format", :requirements => {:id => /[-\d]+/}, :path_prefix => '/:locale'
  map.connect ":controller/:action/:id", :requirements => {:id => /[-\d]+/}, :path_prefix => '/:locale'
  map.connect ":controller/:action.:format", :path_prefix => '/:locale'
  map.connect ":controller/:action", :path_prefix => '/:locale'
end
```

What I want is to have it so when the locale part of the url is omitted it will use the default locale. So this:

/post/show/4 is the same as
/en/post/show/4

and will set the locale to english.

What would be a good way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Find out the current language from the URL and set the `I18n.locale`. For example: = `I18n.locale = 'en'`

See also some [great documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale).

Comment: What I am trying to do is make it work when there is no language sent from the url.

Answer (score 1):

I plan to implement the same approach in my app, though I have not tried it yet. I'm going to use optional route segments, like

```
match '(:locale/)post/show/:id' => 'posts#show'
```

though I think it only works in Rails 3.

Comment: This looks good, I am on 2.3.5 and I don't think my client is keen on upgrading. I will see if there is a similar option.